# Matplotlib x-axis labeling issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

It appears that when I plot my SNR data points across my frequency range the final frequency value is still stuck next to the previous one. Has anyone seen this before or have a solution to this?

```
# Plot the SNR values
        plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))  # Create a new figure object
        plt.plot(frequency, SNR, label='SNR', marker='.')
        plt.xlabel('Frequency [MHz]')
        plt.ylabel('SNR')
        plt.title('SNR vs Frequency')
        plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

I've tried adjusting the length of the plot which has helped with separating the x-axis labels but not with fixing the final label

[image: Here is the plot for reference]

Comment: This looks like the issue might be because your frequencies are strings, rather than numerical data (which means matplotlib will create a "categorical" plot, and explains why "30" gets the first tick, while all other tick spacing is 100. The question then becomes why is the 6000 offset from it's tick: my best guess here would be that perhaps there is a newline (`\n`) character at the end of the string for that label, which has made that a multi-line label, effectively moving the 6000 to the right to make space for the empty second line. Perhaps try interrogating the frequency array first?

Comment: Additionally, making this a [MCVE] would help with the debugging; right now, without your data, the best you can hope for is speculation like my comment above!

Comment: alternative solution might be to convert the frequencies to floats or ints before plotting

Answer (score 1):

Your x-axis values are not evenly spaced, for some reason. The Matplotlib automatic ticker feature got confused.
Proposed solution: try adding this line: `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True, nbins=10))` to force proper ticker spacing. You can adjust the number of bins (`nbins`) as needed.

Your full code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.plot(frequency, SNR, label='SNR', marker='.')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [MHz]')
plt.ylabel('SNR')
plt.title('SNR vs Frequency')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True, nbins=10))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response Marc. 

When I ran it with 10 bins it didn't label 6000 MHz and all the labels were correct. As soon as I added 20 bins it placed a label at the 6000 MHz point and it was offset yet again.

Would it be worth trying to add labels for every other frequency? ie. 30, 200, 400, 600....

Comment: yes, it is possible, coming back to you shortly with code for that..

Comment: I was actually able to get some help from a fellow coworker and got the code to work

Answer (score 0):

This code partially solves the issue:

```
 ax = plt.gca()

        # # Hide every 2nd x-axis label
        n = 2  # Keeps every 2nd label
        for (i, l) in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
            if i <=3:
                continue
            
            if i % n == 0:
                l.set_visible(False)
```

This loop makes visible the first three labels then proceeds to label every other frequency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).